# How to correctly use a JobService?

Tags: android, jobservice

I have implemented an application in Android that uses ***JobService*** to check for updates. I have tested it with some devices: ***Samsung J3, RedMi 5+, RedMi note pro, MI A2 lite***. It is working correctly in ***J3*** but, in other phones that I have tested JobService is not being scheduled if an application is not active or application is not in the recent apps list.

Here is how I have implemented. 
***MainActivity.java***

```
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            JobScheduler js =
                    (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(
                    MY_BACKGROUND_JOB,
                    new ComponentName(context, CheckAdService.class))
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                    .build();
            int resultCode = js.schedule(job);
            if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("JOB", "Scheduled");
            } else {
                Log.d("JOB", "Not Scheduled");
            }
        }
    }
```

***Service.java***

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class CheckAdService extends JobService {

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("NetworkAvailable", "Flag No 2");
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
              ...

            IonDB ionDB = new IonDB(CheckAdService.this, "checkStatus");
            ionDB.getData(new OnDbData() {
                @Override
                public void OnDbDataReceived(JsonObject jsonObject, boolean withError) {
                   ...
                   // after notifying user with news I call jobFinished with rescheduling true option 
                     jobFinished(params, true);

                }
           });
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d("DBDATA", "Job cancelled before completion");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please correct my implementation of JobService so that it works in all android `versions >= LOLLIPOP`. 
Considering that I'm new in Android if I made some coding mistakes please let me know any suggestion.

Comment: What other devices did you tested on?

Comment: Not in many others, but I think that it is not working in MI phones and Android with higher versions @DevMike01

Comment: Are you executing your background work on the same thread as your JobService?

Comment: What version of Android is running your MI phones.

Comment: I guess JobService handles threads itself. @ror

Comment: Android 8.1.0 @DevMike01

Comment: JobService is just a backwards compatible service with some additional features and no thread handling, if you're using newer Android versions use Workmanager instead

Comment: @Mukhammadsher as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService : This means that you must offload your execution logic to another thread/handler/AsyncTask of your choosing. Not doing so will result in blocking any future callbacks from the JobManager

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you will use [worker Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) it will be more correct.
It has capability between the different Android versions.

Comment: Well, I have implemented `workManager` and it is working well in all android versions that I wanted (tested in emulator), but still in **MI** phones if I close the application it is not checking for updates anymore,  Can you help me to tackle this please @Alexander @kkarakk

Comment: I guess the MI phones have a limit for the background process. 
Please, check the settings.
https://www.quora.com/How-to-restrict-background-data-in-Redmi-note-4 
The 2 effective ways for restricting background data will be.